# Dynamics AX 2012 - PurchReqImport Service: The value in field Requisitioner is invalid

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm using the PurchReqImport Service hosted out of the AOT.  Everything is working in terms of the data I'm providing except for an error I mention in the subject.

I've looked at the DB, and it looks like what gets stored there is a record number in a user table.  However, the interface will not accept a valid user name, nor a record number as valid.

I presume the value passed in line.Requisitioner is what the interface is looking at.

What data needs to be passed in this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in a recid from the worker (HcmWorker) table.
This is foreign key field that must match the value in the associated table...you can see all of these in the AOT under the Table>Relations node.

Hope this helps!